# Multiple line plots with different scales

Tags: r, plot, rescale

I'd like to plot time-dependent trend of physical features of music.

For example,

```
from 1980 to 2010, the average song duration (unit: 100000 ms)
from 1980 to 2010, the average loudness (unit: 20dB)
```

You could see they come with different scales, it'll be straightforward to draw line plot over time for each of these features.

But if I have say, 30 such features, so is it appropriate to include all these line plots into the same graph? (Because it'll be kind of waste to draw 30 independent line plot.)

If so, how can I overcome the problem of different scaling(100000ms vs 20dB)? I should re-scale data first?

thx

Comment: Why is it a waste to draw 30 different plots? If your data is properly organised, you can do it in a couple of seconds in R.

Comment: 30 independent plots will take more space, and also for sake of beauty

Comment: Put them on separate plots. A single plot with multiple measures on different scales will be really confusing and will probably force you to use uninformative scales for some of the measures. If the time range is constant, you could do a nice set of vertically-stacked small multiples with each plot scaled to suit the specific measure.

Comment: Yes you guys are right, I'm now plotting independently. Priority is information, not beauty.

Comment: Only other option is I think to plot percentage change relative to 1980 by dividing all values by their 1980 value. That would still give you 30 lines though and only relative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a ggplot approach (illustrated with fake data):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# Fake data
dat = mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg), c(1,3:7,11)]
dat = cbind(dat, setNames(dat, LETTERS[1:7]), setNames(dat, LETTERS[8:14]), 
            setNames(dat, LETTERS[15:21]), setNames(dat[,1:2], LETTERS[22:23]), 
            year=1980:(1980 + nrow(dat) - 1))

# Melt data to long format and plot
ggplot(melt(dat, id.var="year"), aes(year, value)) +
  geom_line(lwd=0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol=5, scales="free_y") +
  theme_tufte(base_size=7) +
  expand_limits(y=0)
```

[image]